# How to give the 7z file the name of the current directory?

Tags: 7-zip

How to compress a directory with 7zip and give the archive file the name of the current directory?

I use the following command line:

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 archive.7z -mhe=on`

Instead of "archive.7z" I need the name of the current directory.

For example, if I compress the directory: "C:\test 1\test 2\test 3", the filename should be "test 2.7z".

Comment: are you doing this from a batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"%~n1"` in place of the filename.  Use quotes, as there may be spaces in the path.

This can only be used in a batch script and not interactively, and you need to use %CD% or `.` as the parameter passed.

eg.

```
my7zscript.bat %cd%
my7zscript.bat .
```